# How to add multiple headers to HttpServletResponse

Tags: java, servlets

I have been trying to do a very simple thing - to send multiple objects using HttpServletResponse response object.For that i am setting multiple objects in response object using setHeader method

```
response.setHeader("instanceDetails",new String(jsonBytes));
response.addHeader("nextStageList",new String(jsonBytes));
```

After adding multiple headers to HttpServletResponse response object in response i am getting "Reload the page to get source for" in firebug.
 However if i send any one header field it is working fine.

```
        response.setHeader("instanceDetails",new String(jsonBytes));
```

I do not understand why setting multiple headers not working and sending one header is working ?

Comment: What is the content you are adding to the header?

Comment: @Hannes The key is some names and value is the String objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Headers are not supposed to contain arbitrary data.
Send your data in the [HTTP Response Entity Body](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec7.html).

You may send data in the entity body like this:

```
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
out.write(jsonBytes);
```

Comment: Thanks @DaniEll. Can you please give some example links for the writing and reading data using HTTP Response Entity Body ?